# How Components are Loading in Single Page React js Application

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie for react js development and trying to find the answers for following questions.

- How child components are loaded into single page
- Does single page load the child components at the time of first 
  loading of the page in web browser?
- Are there any performance impact to page loading time when there are 
  so many child components in parent component of single page app ?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: It is up to you in what way you load your components, you can load everything at once, use lazy loading, or something in between. React does not care.

Comment: I have read it for understanding some concepts in react js,but i could not find the answers for these questions directly.